# please explain error #29 in open layer

Tags: openlayers

I load the map first and then ajax request fetches around 600 locations. However, when I want to plot markers on the map, it disappears.

When I render the map with 'webgl', I receive following error:

`Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/doc/errors/#29 for details`.

error #29 says "x must be greater than 0." please explain this error.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong with your tile grid configuration, or you are trying to set the view to a resolution or extent that is not covered by your tile grid. A full stack trace from an unminified version of OpenLayers (e.g. `ol-debug.js`) should reveal the exact problem.